# Strange Icons on Android Phone Browser

Tags: android, html, mobile

On the following Site are appearing strange icons on android browsers (google chrome): http://knollbeck.de/index.php/impressum

I added a screenshot where you can see it also. I checked the Code  - but I can't find anything which creates this icons.

Do you have an idea?

[image]

Comment: try to change the typeface that you are using

Answer (score 0):

Some char is not able to read(load) by the android browser in German lang. This issue can solve by adding German  .ttf  file and applying font style to the text.

Need to select the required [ttf](http://www.germancorner.com/fonts/) file as per font